# Button below the soft key of iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-interface

Question is, Whether a button can be placed below the software keyboard that comes in the iPhone when we tap to enter some text.
The soft keyboard comes from the very bottom of the screen , can it be made to move little up and a button can be placed ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is impossible with public APIs. Your only other option would be to use a completely [custom input view](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html).

Comment: Thank you. I might sound silly as am new to this , still I have to ask ..In that custom input view can we use built in soft keyboard and will that be just like a normal one ??

Comment: I wouldn’t say it’s totally impossible: there are existing solutions using public APIs that find the keyboard window and add buttons inside it, so it shouldn’t be too hard to adjust the window’s frame and add a button below it. Those solutions are a little rickety by nature, though, and prone to getting broken by OS updates that change the view hierarchy containing the keyboard.

Comment: @DotDmg: No, you would have to replace it. As Noah says, it *might* be possible to find the keyboard's window and move it around, but any solution like that will be very fragile.